# Solving an implicit equation and plot solution

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve numerically a difficult implicit equation and plot the solution. The thing that I want to solve numerically is the following:

> $$ Q(h)=\frac{0.13}{1-10^{-4}\log{\frac{Y(h)}{100}}} $$
>
> $$ P(h)=2*10^{4}*\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-10^{-4}\log{\frac{Y(h)}{100}}}}-1/6$$
>
> $$ Y(h)=\sqrt{3*Q(h)*h^2-(P(h)+1/6)*10^{12}} $$

So the point is that I want to solve (numerically is the only way) the implicit equation of Y(h) in terms of h, but note that functions Q(h) and P(h) also depend on Y (so implicitly on h).

I want to get numerically the solution of Y(h) in order to use this to plot Q(h) and P(h) in terms of h.

Someone knows how to do this??? Thanks!

Expressions in format code:

```
Q[h_] := 0.13/(1 - 10^(-4)*Log[Y[h]/100]);

P[h_] := 2*(10^4)*Sqrt[1/(1 - 10^(-4)*Log[Y[h]/100])] - 1/6;

Y[h_] := Sqrt[3*Q[h]*h^2 - (P[h] + 1/6)*10^12];
```

Comment: What is the range of h and Yh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve your implicit equation as follows:

First I renamed `Y[h]->y`

```
Q[h_] := 0.13/(1 - 10^(-4)*Log[y/100])
P[h_] := 2*(10^4)*Sqrt[1/(1 - 10^(-4)*Log[y/100])] - 1/6
```

which gives the implicit equation

```
zero = y - Sqrt[3*Q[h]*h^2 - (P[h] + 1/6)*10^12] /. y -> Exp[logy] //PowerExpand
```

Thereby I substituted  `y -> Exp[logy]`  because of poor scaling.
The solution of `zero==0` can be evaluated explicitely for h[logy] (not so easy for logy[h])

```
sol = Solve[zero == 0, h ];
ParametricPlot[ {h, Exp[logy]} /. sol, {logy, 0, 25},AxesLabel -> {h, y}, PlotLabel -> zero == 0,PlotRange -> {{-10^9, 10^9}, {0, 10^9 }}]
```

[image]

Q and P can be plotted

```
GraphicsRow[{
ParametricPlot[({h, Q[h]} /. y -> Exp[logy] //PowerExpand) /. sol[[2]], {logy, 0, 25}, AspectRatio -> 1,AxesLabel -> {h, "Q[h]"}], 
ParametricPlot[({h, P[h]} /. y -> Exp[logy] // PowerExpand) /.sol[[2]], {logy, 0, 25}, AspectRatio -> 1,AxesLabel -> {h, "P[h]"}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you it's okay but I was searching to get a plot of Q(h) and P(h) in terms of h, once one has solved the equation for y(h) as you have done. Do you know how do that?

Comment: Where is the problem? You know the solution pairs {h,y}!!! `ParametricPlot[({h, Q[h]} /. y -> Exp[logy] // PowerExpand ) /. 
  sol[[2]], {logy, 0, 25}, AspectRatio -> 1]`